MySQL(5.7.26) query optimization, why select * is much faster that select id in my leading wildcard query?
I have a leading wildcard query I know it is hard to optimize. I know if I use only the trailing wildcard I can do some optimization. But our client wants the leading wildcard because when searching mobile number they always use the last N digits.
The start digits is always 1[3-9]xx, as the mobile format China is always 1[3-9]x-xxxx-xxxx, so using like 136% will get too many results and is not that useful.
select id from customer where seid = 134 and telephone like '%18749618910%'

CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `seid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `ccgeid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' /* foreign key */
  `telephone` varchar(63) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
  `create_time` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`seid`),
  KEY `s_telephone` (`seid`,`telephone`)
  UNIQUE KEY `seid_ccgeid_phone` (`seid`,`ccgeid`,`telephone`),
  KEY `s_cid` (`seid`,`cid`),
)

Resorting to FTS is the long term goal. But since I only need id here I did some experiment to see if I improve some query performance. But I was surprised to see select * ... is faster than select id .... I have around 2.5 millions records, select * alway takes about 1 second while select id takes about 4 to 5 seconds.
The explain Extra information shows select id Using where while select * Using index condition, both with same possible_keys.
But as  Bill Karwin explained in What does MySQl explain Extra "Using where" really mean?, Using where does not help, while I can't find a clear explanation for Using index condition (mysql document does not help).
So why select * is much faster than select id in my case ? Since I need id in the end how do I utilize that to optimize my query ?
Based on the comments I got from @Amadan ("all you need to trigger the ICP optimisation is to return any one column that is not found in the index"), I did some further test to confirm his hypothesis (although I have not fully got it)  that select id, create_time  is as fast as select * because they both use Using index condition while select id, ccgeid is as slow as select id as they both use Using where.
PS. the explain details:
explain select id from customer where seid = 134 and telephone like '%18749618910%'

*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: customer
   partitions: p6
         type: ref
possible_keys: seid_ccgeid_phone,s_cid,s_telephone
          key: s_cid
      key_len: 8
          ref: const
         rows: 1278146
     filtered: 11.11
        Extra: Using where


explain select * from customer where seid = 134 and telephone like '%18749618910%'
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: customer
   partitions: p6
         type: ref
possible_keys: seid_ccgeid_phone,s_cid,s_telephone
          key: seid_ccgeid_phone
      key_len: 8
          ref: const
         rows: 1278146
     filtered: 11.11
        Extra: Using index condition

--- update ---
According to @RickJames suggestion I added FORCE INDEX(s_telephone) to my query and following are the result:

For select *, with or without FORCE INDEX(s_telephone)  there is no obvious performance difference and they both use Using index condition

For select id with FORCE INDEX(s_telephone) there is obvious performance improvement from 4 seconds to around 1.5 seconds, but still slower than select *. It use Using where; Using index now.



SELECT * and SELECT id should, all other factors being the same, have similar execution plans and performance.

Which was why I asked my question.

Right, actually I did some test try to find out why so I clone customer table and did some test. But it was the same table.

Which MySQL version out of curiosity? Does seid=134 really correspond to 11% of table?

Note that LIKE '%...%' cannot use any index. It should not account for the difference in performance you are noticing, but your search would be much more performant if you could refactor that into LIKE '...%' (prefix search).

@danblack 5.7.26, I added that to the question title. And yes seid 134 the company id I query.

@Amadan I know so the long term is to use FTS.

FTS uses words as units; unless you have 18749618910 separated from whatever is before it, I don't think you would get any benefit from it. Separating into two columns (prefix and number) would be able to use a normal index efficiently.

@Amadan I know if I use trailing wildcard I can do some optimization. But our client wants to leading wildcard because when searching mobile number they always use the last 4 digits to do the search. I will add that to my question.

If they always use the last 4 digits to search, then the last 4 digits should be a column being indexed. (Anyway, sorry for the tangent.) As to the EXPLAIN, the docs say that "using index condition" means Index Condition Pushdown Optimization is being utilised. That explains why your second query is faster, but not why it triggers ICP optimisation in the first place, while the first one does not.

Maybe "ICP is used for the range, ref, eq_ref, and ref_or_null access methods when there is a need to access full table rows." Both of your queries are ref; but SELECT id only needs information from index (which maps seid and telephone to id, presumably, so it should have all the info you need). This is just a guess, I am not confident enough to make it an answer.

There's something wrong with MySQL because of the index chosen. While seid_ccgeid_phone is ok, s_telephone is actually better as it should be smaller and would be ideal for both queries (PK is automaticly at the end). Maybe in the 4.5 years of updates since 5.7.26 there has been a fix for this.

@Amadan a little more background about the trailing wildcard use in my case, in China the mobile number always starts with 136, 137 ... so the leading number does not provide much information when query, while the trailing numbers does. But the problem is I don't know whether they remember the last 4 digits or last 3, 5 (last 4 the educated guess), so we have not a column for last 4. But back to my original question I was surprised to see select * is much faster.

I don't think size matters; either index is equally good because you are only using the seid field. If telephone was able to be used, s_telephone would narrow down your rows much better; if I understand it correctly, you would get using index instead of using index condition or using where, with a big performance boost.

Anyway, if my hypothesis is correct, all you need to trigger the ICP optimisation is to return any one column that is not found in the index. SELECT * should run as fast as SELECT id, create_time, but faster than SELECT id, which doesn't get the benefit of the optimisation. I will be curious to see if I am correct.

Also, regarding the telephone index, if I understand your situation correctly - it is always the last N digits being used to search - then it might benefit you to have a column reversed_telephone in your index; if you are looking for a phone ending with 123, reversed_telephone LIKE '321%' should be efficient.

Please test the effectiveness of the index with explicit id value - i.e. by (`seid`,`telephone`,`id`).

@Amadan although I did not fully understand what you said (like how do I get using index) but I tested to find you were right, select id, create_time is basically as fast as select * because they both used "Using index condition" while select id, ccgied is the same as select id because they both use  "Using where". Why is that ? BTW, I will add this to my question.

How big (MB) is the table?   What is the setting of innodb_buffer_pool_size?  Is the table ENGINE=InnoDB?

Did you run each timing twice?  (The first time may have been I/O-bound; the second might be 10x faster because of caching.)

It looks like the table is partitioned?  Please provide the PARTITIONing information.  The definition of p6 and the other partitions is probably relevant.

@TimBiegeleisen - I disagree.  SELECT id usually (including this case) can be performed by a "covering" index ("Using index"), which will usually be faster than SELECT * (assuming no index is "covering").

Sounds like a bug -- s_telephone is "covering" for SELECT id, but the Optimizer did not pick it.

@Qiulang - As an experiment, please try IGNORE(s_cid) for SELECT id.  (Provide timing and EXPLAIN).

Might declaring telephone to be ascii_bin run faster?

IF THE TABLE IS MyISAM, MUCH OF THE DISCUSSION HERE IS INVALID.

@RickJames it is InnoDB. I run show to get  PARTITIONing as /*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (seid)  PARTITIONS 128 */;  About ignore I think it doesn't apply to select, so I don't get that one. We have a rule to not use ascii_bin but varchar (I don't fully agree though)

@RickJames even before I asked the question I had always run commands twice but I didn't notice the apparent time difference as you said, which was also confused me. I didn't bring that up in my question, feared that may sidetrack my question (why select * is faster than select id in my case)

Partition by hash is essentially useless.  I have not found a single use case for it.  (But I am now scratching my head to see if this is such a use case.)

Please test each query with FORCE INDEX(s_telephone) added.  (I'm trying to distinguish between Optimizer problem versus Hash benefit.)

I'll try to collate everything I wrote in comments.

LIKE '%...%' criteria cannot use indices to directly find the rows; LIKE '...%' criteria can.

This means, telephone like '%18749618910%' cannot directly utilise any of the indices to speed up the search.

This means, the only column that can be found using index is seid; since indices must be used left-to-right, three indices are equally eligible (i.e. for the purposes of your query, any of the indices starting with seid can be used, since none of the other index fields are useful).

This means, your query cannot just use the index to find your data; it can filter on seid using the index, but then has to search the found rows one by one to find which ones match the telephone = '%...%' pattern.

MySQL can do this in two ways. One is the naive way that does just that: filters the rows using the index, then filters the resultant rows again by inspecting each row. This is Using where strategy.
The other strategy is the procedure called Index Condition Pushdown Optimization. It speeds up this process in certain situations. Here is the description from that page:

Index Condition Pushdown (ICP) is an optimization for the case where MySQL retrieves rows from a table using an index. Without ICP, the storage engine traverses the index to locate rows in the base table and returns them to the MySQL server which evaluates the WHERE condition for the rows. With ICP enabled, and if parts of the WHERE condition can be evaluated by using only columns from the index, the MySQL server pushes this part of the WHERE condition down to the storage engine. The storage engine then evaluates the pushed index condition by using the index entry and only if this is satisfied is the row read from the table. ICP can reduce the number of times the storage engine must access the base table and the number of times the MySQL server must access the storage engine.


So: when ICP is not active, MySQL server asks the storage engine looks into the index, finds all rows where seid = 134, gives them to the server, which then asks the engine for each of those rows in order to be able to confirm telephone LIKE '%18749618910%'

When ICP is active, MySQL server asks the storage engine to look at the index to find the rows where seid = 134, but also asks it to confirm the telephone criterion, because the index also contains the telephone data. It cannot be used for searching, but it can be evaluated; so the storage engine doesn't need to load the table row, and can evaluate whether or not telephone LIKE '%18749618910%' just based on the information found in the index entries of the seid = 134 rows. This cuts back on the back-and-forth communication between the MySQL server and the storage engine.

The ICP optimisation page specifies the cases where it can be employed:

"ICP is used for the range, ref, eq_ref, and ref_or_null access methods when there is a need to access full table rows.

So it seems that we have three possible cases here:

If all the criteria can be found using the index, the Using index strategy is optimal. This is not your case (because of non-prefix LIKE).

If some of the criteria can be found using the index, and some other criteria can be evaluated from the index, and there is a need to access full table rows, ICP (Using index condition) can be used. This is your second case (since * and create_time need information that cannot be found in the index, and the full table row is required).

If the other criteria can be neither found nor evaluated using the index, or if there is no need to access full table rows, ICP cannot be used, and the regular Using where strategy must be used. This is your first case (since id and ccgeid can be read from the index being used for the filtering, removing the need to read the table row).



Of course, the first (and best) case is not currently available to you, because telephone in your schema is not searchable using an index.

If the search is always for the last N characters of telephone, my advice is to create a column reversed_telephone. For example, if telephone is 123456789, then reversed_telephone should be 987654321. To search for the last 3 digits (789), look for reversed_telephone LIKE '987%'. To search for the last 5 digits (56789), look for reversed_telephone LIKE '98765%'. This way you do not need to care whether the customer remembers 3, 4 or 5 digits; the only requirement is that they know the end. Using INDEX (seid, reversed_telephone), you would fall into case 1 above, the optimal strategy, regardless of which fields you SELECT.



So it is quite counter-intuitive that the need to access full table row actually speeds up the query, especially in my case I just need id in the end. Let me do some more research before I accept your answer. Thanks for spending time and effort into my question.

Good discussion of ICP.

Hi guys I tried FORCE INDEX(s_telephone) per @RickJames suggestion and updated my question. Can you take a look ? So even with "using index" , select id is still slower than select *

The plot thickens.  Sorry, I am out of ideas.

I believe I answered how to speed both of them up, in my last paragraph.

@Amadan I have accepted your answer but I reason I also brought that to you was with FORCE INDEX(s_telephone) I got Using index for select id, but it is still slower than select * and you said "the Using index strategy is optimal. So that still remains a question to me.

I did not say just forcing to use an index is optimal. I said constructing an index such that supplementary filtering is not necessary, like in my last paragraph, is optimal.

@Amadan I was referring to these words "1. If all the criteria can be found using the index, the Using index strategy is optimal." in your answer and one of your original comments "if I understand it correctly, you would get using index instead of using index condition or using where, with a big performance boost.".  But now with FORCE INDEX(s_telephone) I got Using index it was still slower than select * (which using index condition). I was not talking about your last paragraph.

First point in my answer: "LIKE '%...%' criteria cannot use indices to directly find the rows". So "If all criteria can be found using the index" is false, whichever index you use. As long as you have telephone like '%18749618910%' in your query, you cannot achieve the optimal strategy. I believe I said it repeatedly, whether in comments or in my answer.
